# How would I get the length of a string without bbcode tags?

Tags: php, bbcode, string-length

I have a custom bb code script with two sets of arrays.  The first array is the set of the bb tags, the second is the html tags.  I would like to find the length of a user's post, but not including the content of the tags.  For example, [b]Hello, world![/b] would be a length of 12 because of the string inside the tags.  Something like [img]http://www.mydomain.com/images/myimage.gif[/img] would be 0.

I want to find this because I would like to have an "experience point" system where users earn XP for making threads and replies, but I do not want them to earn points for tags like that.

```
$find = array(
            "'\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]'is",
            "'\[i\](.*?)\[/i\]'is",
            "'\[u\](.*?)\[/u\]'is",
            "'\[s\](.*?)\[/s\]'is",
            "'\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]'is",
            "'\[url\](.*?)\[/url\]'i",
            "'\[url=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/url\]'i",
            "'\[link\](.*?)\[/link\]'i",
            "'\[link=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/link\]'i",
            "'\[h1\](.*?)\[\/h1\]'is",
            "'\[h2\](.*?)\[\/h2\]'is",
            "'\[h3\](.*?)\[\/h3\]'is",
            "'\[ul\](.*?)\[\/ul\]'is",
            "'\[li\](.*?)\[\/li\]'is",
            "'\[p\](.*?)\[\/p\]'is"
        );

        $replace = array(
            '<strong>\1</strong>',
            '<em>\1</em>',
            '<u>\1</u>',
            '<s>\1</s>',
            '<img src="\1" \1alt="User Image" />',
            '<a href="\1">\1</a>',
            '<a href="\1">\2</a>',
            '<a href="\1">\1</a>',
            '<a href="\1">\2</a>',
            '<h1>\1</h1>',
            '<h2>\1</h2>',
            '<h3>\1</h3>',
            '<ul>\1</ul>',
            '<li>\1</li>',
            '<p>\1</p>'
        );
```

Comment: can you clarify your question at all... `[b]Hello, world![/b] would be a length of 12 because of the string inside the tags.` What are you not counting? spaces of punctuation? because this string should be 13. Are points being awarded for longer strings? What does XP points have to do with string length?? no points for strings tags like that??

Answer (score 0):

Combine strlen() with the preg pattern in the accepted answer of this post: [How to remove BB codes from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648716/how-to-remove-bb-codes-from-a-string)

For HTML, use strip_tags(). http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php